# Can I use Set Variable in ADF to generate array of dates between given Start and End dates?

Tags: variables, set

I've ADF pipeline where Start_date and Diff_days are given as input parameter. Like in Python I can generate all dates in list using datetime.timedelta, can I get the list of dates in ADF Set Variable using these two inputs?
if Start_date='2020-01-01', Diff_days=10, expected is to get list of 10 dates- 2020-01-01 to 2020-01-10.